# How to solve using bitwise operators

Tags: c

I wanted to find out efficiently which drawers are Full. But the output has to be a number corresponding to the binary representation. For example if only the second Drawer is full (from left to right), then the output is 4:

8 4 2 1

0 1 0 0 (Drawer Two is Full)

So I used this approach.

```
int DrawersFull[4] = {0,0,0,0}; //Initially all are empty

for(i=0;i<4;i++)
{

    if(IsDrawerFull) // the api was provided by the interviewer
      DrawerFull[i]=1;
}
```

I am not sure how to generate the output. Any suggestions will be helpful. Thanks.
Interviewer gave me hint that it can be done using bitwise operators but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you talking about arrays or bitwise operators (you don't seem to use any of the latter)? Also your loop should be `for(i=0;i<4;i++)`.

Comment: Are you trying to return an `int` describing which drawers are full?

Comment: Question is not clear. Is your input numbers : (8,4,2,1) or your outputs? What is the form of output - an array or unspecified (could be a scalar) ? This is a base 2 arithmetic problem, but your problem description is unclear.

Comment: I believe the '8 4 2 1' represents the values of the binary places. The IsDrawerFull function is an api that will set the array to the correct values depending on what drawers are full. He is asking how to calculate a value using bitwise operations that corresponds directly to the values in that array.

Comment: Since the question is on hold, I can't answer it... Here's my solution : `int res = 0; for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { if (IsDrawerFull(i)) res |= 8 >> i; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same as converting binary number to decimal. Try this one:

```
int res = 0;
for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
    res = res * 2 + DrawerFull[i]; // Assuming DrawerFull will contain only 1 or 0.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char fullDrawers = 0;
for( char i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
    if( IsDrawerFull )
        fullDrawers &= 1;
    fullDrawers <<= 1;
}
```